# What is the library m in C++ linker?

Tags: c++

Following [this guide](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Eclipse#.UzgDN_nEKG4), it says to include a library in the C++ Linker called `m`. What is this for?

Specifically, [Your second Arduino project](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Eclipse#YourSecondArduinoProject).

4) **Configure project**

5th dot point:

> AVR C++ Linker -> Libraries: Under libraries, add arduino_core and m (in that order). Under path, add the path to the correct core library, e.g. "`${workspace_loc:/arduino_core/328P_16MHz}`"

Comment: Bewared of this tutorial that seems quite old and is probably not uptodate now. Note that if you want to use Eclipse, I'd suggest to take a look at this plugin: http://eclipse.baeyens.it/ I use it everyday (currently using 1.2.5.5 as I have not yet installed Arduino IDE 1.5).

Comment: @jfpoilpret Is that using the compiler shipped with the Arduino I DE? I actually decided not to use Arduino and go for full fledged C...

Comment: Yes it uses the AVR tools that come installed with Arduino IDE. But you can do full-fledged C or C++ with it if you want as it does not perform default `#include`s like Arduino IDE.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Do you have access to strings and vectors?

Comment: I haven't checked that but I'd rather stay away from STL and involved dynamic memory allocations for embedded development.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if AVR tools support templates as required for STL usage.

Comment: @jfpoilpret You can use at least strings in the Arduino IDE, which is one of the many reasons why I'm moving to C instead...

Comment: Standard C++ also supports the same kind of `string` class (maybe the same? I have not checked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The m library is the "math" library. You have to link with it in most flavours of gnu compilers (it is typically not required in other, as it is included in the standard lib) when using functions and stuff from the header file "math.h".

Comment: Is this a library that the compiler knows where is by itself?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to indicate "-lm" as an option to the compiler-linker. No necessity to indicate -L(pathToLib).